# Test a single-line file for punctuation and newline

Tags: python, io

I have written the following program to read from a file (entire input in single line) and check for:

- ASCII punctuation characters
- a final newline

```
import re
file_name=input("Please enter the file name ")
with open(file_name, 'r') as fp:
    context=fp.read()
    regex = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|} {~]')
    if regex.search(context) is None: 
        print("No special character found")
    else: 
        print("Special character found") 
    for x in range(0,len(context)-1):
        if (context[x].isspace())==True:
            print("spaces found in the file at ", x)
            break
        else:
            pass
        #print("No space found")
    for x in range(0, len(context)-1):
        if context[x]=='\n' or context[x]=='"':
            print("Yes new line is there at", x)
            break
        else:
            pass
        #print("No new line ")
```

Comment: What is the benefit of getting the **position** of just the **1st** space or newline char IF there could be multiple of such? (that's what your code is doing now) And why should `\n` and `"` be equivalents?

Comment: My code is to find find all new lines, and spaces and special characters.

Comment: @naryana, when you said **all** - that directly contradicts with your current code which `break`s on the 1st occurrence. Your code is not working as expected.

Comment: Please help me to get it correct.

Comment: The point is that direct fixing is **out** of scope on this site - you'd need to post already working code

Comment: Thanks for your findings, thanks a lot . I will fix the issues that you have identified

Comment: Ok, update your code appropriately

Comment: Because of break statement its not getting repeated

Comment: You did not update your code according to your statement "find **all** new lines, and spaces and special characters"

Answer (score 5):

`\|` is not a proper escape sequence.  To include the backslash in the string, it should be escaped using two backslashes, or you should use a “raw” string for the regular expression, so backslashes do not need to be escaped.

`for x in range(0, len(context) - 1):` does not check the last character of the string, since `range(start, end)` already does not include `end`.

`if (context[x].isspace())==True:` does not need the parentheses around `context[x].isspace()`, nor does it need the `== True`.

You can use `enumerate()` to loop over the contents of an iterable and get the index at the same time.  Also, a `for ... else` block can be used to detect if nothing was found.  With Python 3.6 or later, f-strings can be used to embed variables directly in strings.

```
for idx, ch in enumerate(context):
    if ch.isspace():
        print(f"spaces found in the file at {idx}")
        break
else:
    print("no space found")
```

It is strange to find a quotation mark, and declare that a new line has been found.  Are you sure you’ve got your logic correct?

PEP8 Guidelines:

- spaces around all operators, like `=`, `==`, `-`
- use a space after each comma in argument lists
- blank line after imports
- longer, descriptive variable names (`x` is too short and not descriptive)

Comment: Yes. I need to have only text that to in single line. No new lines, no spaces and no special characters to be found.